# Resolve network connection failure caused by settings

Tags: networking, 16.04, server

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04 server hosted by Vultr.
I was planning to setup PPTP and found [this document](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-ppp-vpn-on-debian-ubuntu), so i followed that and rebooted the server. And now server is offline.
Describes at full length, everything's working well except network. I can't send or get ping, can't use "apt update" command on server. Of course, i can't access from outside so i can't do SSH, FTP, and Http connection.

So the only way i can access to server is using VNC console that provided by hosting company.

So the question is...

1. What did i do wrong? What was happened when i followed that document?
2. What should i do to recover network failure?
3. If there aren't any way to recover settings by myself, then deploy New Instance and copy network settings by hand can be a solution? And if it can be, what settings should be copied?

EDIT: `ip a s`, `ip r s`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/hosts` screenshot added:
[image: ip a s, ip r s, cat /etc/resolv.conf, cat /etc/hosts]
EDIT2: `cat /etc/hostname` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` screenshot added:
[cat /etc/hostname, cat /etc/network/interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFIVS.png)
Actually, there were no `auto etho ~ gateway ***.***.***.***` line after that accident, so i manually added that.

Comment: please give us some more data to work on: `ip a s`, `ip r s`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`and `cat /etc/hosts`.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann Here's the result of that command.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKpwg.png

Comment: May we also see: `cat /etc/hostname` And also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I uploaded that, and Thanks for welcoming :-D

Comment: OK, I entered recovery mode after rebooting, and i recovered network, and problem solved. Though i don't know what was happened and does it really recovered everything what i touched :-P

Comment: And now UFW isn't working. It's time to make another question ;-X

Answer (score 0):

Your file `/etc/hosts` suggests that your hostname is *install* but `/etc/hostname` says *vultr*. I suggest that you change one or the other to match and immediately reboot.

Also, your file `/etc/network/interfaces` needs a DNS declartion for IPv4 also. I suggest that you add, just below `gateway ***.***.***.***` the following:

```
 dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

...or any other suitable IPv4 DNS nameservers.

Get the system to re-read the file and use the changes:

```
 sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Did you connect?

```
 ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Changed _installed_ to _vultr_ on `/etc/hosts` and rebooted, failed. Add `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` on `/etc/network/interfaces`, failed.  `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0` also failed to bring up eth0, but got interesting message, `run-parts: failed to exec /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/route: Exec format error`, and exited with return code 1. Its contents are same as scripts that mentioned on document.

Comment: If you check: `cat /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/route`, is the last line actually `EOF`? This suggests that it should not be: http://edlinlink.github.io/Setup_PPTP_VPN_on_Ubuntu_Vultr_VPS.html If yours is, I suggest amending it. Reboot.